# Crossbar capital I letter in Unicode

Tags: unicode

In comics lettering some authors differentiate between a "capital i with crossbars" and a "capital i without crossbars", generally using the crossbars version for the first personal pronoun, and the other for ordinary words. An example can be seen in this [picture from Dave Gibbon's lettering in Watchmen](http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2012/08/comicsans2.jpg).

I was wondering if there is an Unicode code point for the "capital i with crossbars" gliph different by the normal latin one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/49/index.htm lists no such related letter. You might find a font set where e.g. ROMAN NUMERAL ONE is rendered differently from the regular LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I but Unicode currently does not seem to currently have a pair of glyphs with this precise distinction.

**Update:** According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C9%AA#Encoding) this was introduced in Unicode 9.0 (2016).  Thanks @pelson for the link!

Comment: Yes, there seems to be no proper "alternate capital i" point. Thanks for the reference, it was pretty useful.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to suggest this may have changed (June 2016) with the introduction of "Latin capital letter small capital I". The unicode character that it produces isn't quite what I'm after though.... i.e. see ɪ vs I

Comment: @pelson Thanks!! Updated.